# What does vcxproj.user file do?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, vcxproj

If we create new project files in visual studio 2022,
we get 3 files; vcxproj(project files), vcxproj.filter(filtering files), and vcxproj.user.

On https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/project-and-solution-files?view=msvc-170,
it says that the file (vcxproj.user) is the migration user file.

What does "migrating" mean? and why do we need to migrate the file?

I have no idea what the file does.

Comment: Clumsy text, that was written back in the VS2010 days when projects had to be migrated from the .vcproj format used in VS2008 to the new .vcxproj format.  Forget about "migration" today.  The .vcxproj.user file contains settings that are user-specific instead of project-specific.  And thus probably shouldn't be stored in source control.  Project > Properties > Debugging settings end up in there.